# Between nginx and lighttpd, which one suits best the needs of a web-app (SaaS) and why?

Tags: linux, web-applications, nginx, webserver, lighttpd

Between nginx and lighttpd, which one suits the needs of a web-app (SaaS) best and why?

I seek to find out:

Which one takes advantage of the hardware its running on, which one scales the best, which one shares the load better, which one is more secure in terms of DoS attacks, common abuse attacks et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) is the answer.

But if you want to stick with older technology, then nginx is fundamentally an async server and there is an open API to build plugins if you need that.

But seriously, do look at Mongrel2 because message queueing (even zeroMQ) is a better way to handle scaling.

Comment: Hello,
I am looking at Mongrel2.

Can you please tell though why else is it better than the rest?

How secure is it against all sorts of "lame" attacks?

I'm intending to run Node.JS behind it. Will it suit?

Thank you.